# How to read a file with square brackets?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Disease, ICD10_2023, ICD10_2019, ubk_coding_19, problem
Alzheimer_Disease, [G30, F00], [G30, F00], [G30, F00], -
Malaria, [B50, B51, B52, B53, B54, P37.3, P37.4], [B50, B51, B52, B53, B54, P37.3, P37.4], [B50, B51, B52, B53, B54, P373, P374], !
Spinocerebellar_ataxia, [G11], [G11], [G11], -
```

How can I read this file in R? I'd like to have lists as elements in the dataframe, meaning that for column ICD10_2023 for example you would have:  `c(G30, F00), c(B50, B51, B52, B53, B54, P37.3, P37.4), c(G11)`

I was simply doing this:
`read.csv("example.txt")` 
I get this error:
 `Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :  more columns than column names`

Instead when doing it with header=FALSE the format is destroyed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `read.table`/`read.csv` requires that there be an equal number of delimited fields in your file, and you don't because the bracketed data is not quoted. I think we can work around that using `pipe` and the command-line `sed` utility.

```r
res <- read.csv(pipe(r"(sed -E 's/\[/"[/g ; s/\]/]"/g' /tmp/foo)"))
res
#                  Disease                               ICD10_2023                               ICD10_2019                          ubk_coding_19 problem
# 1      Alzheimer_Disease                               [G30, F00]                               [G30, F00]                             [G30, F00]       -
# 2                Malaria  [B50, B51, B52, B53, B54, P37.3, P37.4]  [B50, B51, B52, B53, B54, P37.3, P37.4]  [B50, B51, B52, B53, B54, P373, P374]       !
# 3 Spinocerebellar_ataxia                                    [G11]                                    [G11]                                  [G11]       -
```

where `/tmp/foo` is the text file.

For breaking them down into components in list-columns, we can do

```r
res[,2:4] <- lapply(res[,2:4], function(z) strsplit(gsub("[][ ]", "", z), ","))
res
#                  Disease                            ICD10_2023                            ICD10_2019                       ubk_coding_19 problem
# 1      Alzheimer_Disease                              G30, F00                              G30, F00                            G30, F00       -
# 2                Malaria B50, B51, B52, B53, B54, P37.3, P37.4 B50, B51, B52, B53, B54, P37.3, P37.4 B50, B51, B52, B53, B54, P373, P374       !
# 3 Spinocerebellar_ataxia                                   G11                                   G11                                 G11       -
str(res)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Disease      : chr  "Alzheimer_Disease" "Malaria" "Spinocerebellar_ataxia"
#  $ ICD10_2023   :List of 3
#   ..$ : chr  "G30" "F00"
#   ..$ : chr  "B50" "B51" "B52" "B53" ...
#   ..$ : chr "G11"
#  $ ICD10_2019   :List of 3
#   ..$ : chr  "G30" "F00"
#   ..$ : chr  "B50" "B51" "B52" "B53" ...
#   ..$ : chr "G11"
#  $ ubk_coding_19:List of 3
#   ..$ : chr  "G30" "F00"
#   ..$ : chr  "B50" "B51" "B52" "B53" ...
#   ..$ : chr "G11"
#  $ problem      : chr  " -" " !" " -"
```

Notes:

- in the first block, I use R's newish raw-strings `r"(...)"` because the use of escaped backslashes in the `sed` expressions could easily get into Inception-level backslashing, I chose to keep it simple;
- what we do is replace all `[` with `"[` and similarly `]` to `]"`, so that `read.csv` will correctly recognize a quoted cell for what it is; this fails if any of your brackets are not paired
- if your filename has spaces, you'll need to internally quote `/tmp/foo`, since R's use of `pipe` and such are naive to that sort of thing

Answer (score 3):

Read in the lines, replace each of [ and ] with double quote, re-read that and strsplit each column.

```
library(dplyr)

"example.csv" %>%
  readLines() %>%
  chartr("[]", '""', .) %>%
  read.csv(text = .) %>%
  mutate(across(-1, ~ strsplit(trimws(.x), ", ")))
```